# Query to get all customers when firstName and/or lastName is specified

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am working on creating a API using RESTful [Spring boot framework, Hibernate, Java 11]. Here, am trying to implement a query to get all customers when firstName and/or lastName is specified.
So,

1. Both first and last names can be specified together.
2. Either first or last name alone can be specified by the user.

I tried to implement both these cases in 1 API. But, didn't get the expected result.
These are my classes:

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class PersonEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
}
```

My Repository class:

```
import com.customer.data.management.entity.PersonEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonEntity, Long> {

    @Query("select u from PersonEntity u where u.firstName = ?1 or u.lastName = ?2")
    List<PersonEntity> searchByFirstAndOrLastName(String firstName, String lastName);
}
```

Here is my Service interface:

```
import com.ustomer.data.management.entity.PersonEntity;
import com.customer.data.management.exception.BadRequestException;
import com.customer.data.management.exception.NotFoundException;

import java.util.List;

public interface PersonService {

    List<PersonEntity> searchByFirstAndOrLastName(String firstName, String lastName);
}
```

Then my ServiceImpl class:

```
import com.customer.data.management.entity.PersonEntity;
import com.customer.data.management.exception.BadRequestException;
import com.customer.data.management.exception.NotFoundException;
import com.customer.data.management.repository.PersonRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
 
@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService{

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository repository; 

      
    @Override
    public List<PersonEntity> searchByFirstAndOrLastName(String firstName, String lastName) {

        List<PersonEntity> customers =  repository.searchByFirstAndOrLastName(firstName, lastName);

        if(customers.size() > 0) {
            return customers;
        } else {
            return new ArrayList<PersonEntity>();
        }
    }
}
```

My controller class:

What changes should I make to my query in Repository class to achieve this ?

Comment: try to concat both firstname and lastname together, and then use like operator. some Pseudocode is like this
"select u from PersonEntity u where concat( u.firstName,u.lastName) like '%?1%'   "  
List<PersonEntity> searchByFirstAndOrLastName(String fullname_without_space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `:column is null` as `or` condition with column so that column will be ignored when the column search value is `null`

```
@Query("select u from PersonEntity u where (:firstName is null or u.firstName = :firstName)"
      +" and (:lastName is null or u.lastName = :lastName)")
List<PersonEntity> searchByFirstAndOrLastName(@Param("firstName") String firstName,
                                              @Param("lastName") String lastName);
```

*Case Analysis:*

- For case search by firstName and lastName it's work like

  `u.firstName = :firstName and u.lastName = :lastName`
- For case search by firstName and lastName is null it's work like

  `u.firstName = :firstName and true`
- For case search by lastName and firstName is null it's work like

  `true and u.lastName = :lastName`